# Does Kendo UI have a CSS reference?

Tags: kendo-ui

We are currently using twitter Bootstrap for its grid system, navigation and input styling.  In working with Kendo UI, we noticed that it has a theme system.

Is there a reference available on how to use the Kendo UI classes?

We imagine Kendo classes would replace our input and navigation markup, but what about our grid system?  Does Kendo UI have a built-in CSS grid system?

Comment: Use their grid? Use the css classes/structure their grid plugin uses? You'll have to look at the CSS yourself. There is no guide.

Comment: Their Grid is a Data Grid widget, not a layout grid.

Answer (score 3):

Only the documentation of the classes. There's quite a bit of information but it's not exhaustive.

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/appearance-styling

Comment: There was a blog post from some time ago by Burke Holland (of the Kendo team) about using the kendo classes in a form. It mostly uses classes for inputs and buttons, but may help some.  http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-04-16/styling-forms-like-a-pro-with-kendo-ui.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is ancient now but just for anyone still wondering about the last part of the question:

> We imagine Kendo classes would replace our input and navigation markup, but what about our grid system? Does Kendo UI have a built-in CSS grid system?

The answer to that is NO.  Kendo has a data grid widget but no layout grid at this point in time.  But they do keep adding to it. Their stuff is sort of compatible with the Bootstrap grid but if for instance you want to use the Bootstrap grid inside of a Kendo Window widget you need to adjust for the fact that they use different box sizing models:

```
/*=====================================================================*/
/* Box-sizing fix for using Bootstrap grid layout inside Kendo widgets */
/*=====================================================================*/
/* reset everything to the default box model */
*,
:before,
:after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late but, just in case, there's a workaround. Fire up their handy [ThemeBuilder](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/). Click on "Download." Then look through the `kendo.custom.css` file they have. Lists all the CSS classes in plain sight.

You can also look through their `kendo.all.css` or `kendo.common.css` (depending on if you have their professional or open-source offering) in the `src` folder that came with your Kendo-UI download.